# jQuery autocomplete in slickGrid setWidth of suggestions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete, slickgrid

I have an editor with an autocomplete textfield in slickGrid. 
This looks (simplified) like this:

```
 function AutoCompleteEditor(args) {
 var $input;

 this.init = function () {
   $input = $("<INPUT id='tags' class='editor-text' />");
   $input.appendTo(args.container);  
   $input.bind("keydown.nav", function (e) {
        if (e.which === $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.which === $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT) {
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
        if((e.which === $.ui.keyCode.DOWN) || (e.which === $.ui.keyCode.UP)){ 
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        } 
        if(e.which === $.ui.keyCode.RETURN){ 
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
      })
   $input.focus().select();

   $input.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(request, response) {
              .....
           },
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          event.target.value = ui.item.label;
          return false;
        },
        open: function( event, ui ) { 
          $(this).autocomplete( "widget" )
            .find( "ui-menu-item-alternate" )
              .removeClass( "ui-menu-item-alternate" )
            .end()
            .find( "li.ui-menu-item:odd a" )
              .addClass( "ui-menu-item-alternate" );  
        },
        appendTo: args.container,   
        width: 500,
    });

 };
```

Now, I have 2 problems:

1) The suggestion list is just a little narrower than the editor field. But I would like it even wider - possibly as wide as the widest item in it

2) I have disabled the up and down arrow keys for the entry field, but it does not focus the list so that the arrows would select the suggestion item.

Any thoughts what is wrong in my code?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer first question.

you can change the css of autocomplete class

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden;

}
/* IE 6 doesn't support max-height
 * we use height instead, but this forces the menu to always be this tall
 */
* html .ui-autocomplete 
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Please find below code make it  up and down event null
 $.widget( "ui.autocomplete", {
options: {
    appendTo: "body",
    autoFocus: false,
    delay: 300,
    minLength: 1,
    position: {
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        collision: "none"
    },
    source: null
},

pending: 0,

_create: function() {
    var self = this,
        doc = this.element[ 0 ].ownerDocument,
        suppressKeyPress;
    this.isMultiLine = this.element.is( "textarea" );

    this.element
        .addClass( "ui-autocomplete-input" )
        .attr( "autocomplete", "off" )
        // TODO verify these actually work as intended
        .attr({
            role: "textbox",
            "aria-autocomplete": "list",
            "aria-haspopup": "true"
        })
        .bind( "keydown.autocomplete", function( event ) {
if ( self.options.disabled || self.element.propAttr( "readOnly" ) ) {
                return;
            }

            suppressKeyPress = false;
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;
            switch( event.keyCode ) {
            case keyCode.PAGE_UP:
                //self._move( "previousPage", event );
                break;
            case keyCode.PAGE_DOWN:
                //self._move( "nextPage", event );
                break;
            case keyCode.UP:
                //self._keyEvent( "previous", event );
                break;
            case keyCode.DOWN:
                //self._keyEvent( "next", event );
                break;
            case keyCode.ENTER:
            case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                // when menu is open and has focus
                if ( self.menu.active ) {
                    // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
                    // which causes forms to submit
                    suppressKeyPress = true;
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                //passthrough - ENTER and TAB both select the current element
            case keyCode.TAB:
                if ( !self.menu.active ) {
                    return;
                }
                self.menu.select( event );
                break;
            case keyCode.ESCAPE:
                self.element.val( self.term );
                self.close( event );
                break;
                // changes done by justin close the menu if text is empty
                case keyCode.BACKSPACE:                 
                break;
                //****************end *******************
            default:
                // keypress is triggered before the input value is changed
                clearTimeout( self.searching );
                self.searching = setTimeout(function() {
                    // only search if the value has changed
                    //if ( self.term != self.element.val() ) {
                        self.selectedItem = null;
                        self.search( null, event );
                    //}
                }, self.options.delay );
                break;
            }
        })
```

Comment: Sorry, I could not reproduce what you are doing here.
Obviously, you are catching the key from the menu. But I think my focus stays in the edit field (which would be right because I might want to type again or so).
I would need to catch the up and down arrow key in the edit box (which I do) and select the next or previous suggestion. For that action I cannot find a function